# What is Tcl and why do I need it to build applications using cx freeze and what is LSOpenURLsWithRole()?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tcl, cx-freeze

I'm trying to build my application into an .app file and I kept hitting the following error.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Tcl'
```

So I downloaded *ActiveTcl8.5* and the error went away. Now I'm able to build using the following command:

```
python3 setup_cx_freeze.py bdist_dmg
```

But my application runs and immediately closes. I ran it from the cmd to get a sense as to what the error is and the only feedback I'm getting is LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810. What am I doing wrong? Why did I need Tcl in order to use cx freeze and why does my app not want to open? This is my setup file.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ['tkinter', 'smb.SMBConnection'], "excludes": [], "includes": [], "include_files":['Project_Images', 'Project_Docs'], "bin_path_excludes": []}

setup(
    name = "Test",
    version = "2.51",
    description = "Will this even work?",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("AccuAdmin.py")])
```

Comment: Well, it needs Tcl/Tk because it is using the tkinter python extension for the GUI.  (advertisement) Tk is the easiest, fastest cross-platform GUI.

Answer (score 1):

[Tcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) is a programming language, invented at roughly the same time as Python. Tkinter is a thin wrapper on top of an embedded tcl interpreter with the "tk" widget extension. You cannot use tkinter without tcl/tk.

Comment: So Tcl should have already been on my computer if Python was installed since Tkinter comes with Python and Tkinter needs Tcl to run correct? Because I noticed that after downloading the Tcl/tk framework again it broke all the applications I started creating using py2app. As in I couldn't open them it wasn't until I deleted those frameworks that I was able to open them again.Why would cx freeze be looking in the wrong location?

Comment: @terratunaz: I do not know. I've never used cx_freeze. Your question  asked what tcl is and why you need it.